# Angularjs single click fires 2 times?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

```
<button id="voterListSearchButton" class="serachButton" ng-click="onSearchButton1Click()">search</button>
```

This is my search button:

```
$scope.onSearchButton1Click = function() {
    var partId = $("#partIdSearch").val();
    var firstName = $("#firstNameSearch").val();
    var lastName = $("#lastNameSearch").val();
    var fathersName = $("#fathersNameSearch").val();
    var address = $("#address").val();
    $rootScope.$broadcast('onSearchButton1Click',partId,firstName,fathersName,lastName,address);
}
```

This is my controller for the above button. I broadcast this event to another controller in the following way:

```
$scope.$on('onSearchButton1Click',function(event,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5){
    pId= data1;
    fname=data2;
    lname=data3;
    fathersName=data4;
    address= data5;

    VoterDataService.search(data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,0).success(function(response){
        $scope.arr = response.search;    
    });
});
```

This is my service code:

```
voterDataServiceAPI.search = function(data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,pageNo,lang) {
    var url ="api/search" + "?part_id="+data1 +"&first_name="+data2+"&middle_name="+data3+"&last_name="+data4+"&subpart=" + data5 +"&page_no="+pageNo;
    return $http({
        method : "GET",
        url:url,
        headers:{
            "content-type": "application/json"
        }
    });
}
```

Why single click fires 2 times?

Comment: I think your controller called two times !!!

Comment: If you already create a service and then why you do a broadcast rather than call the service method directly from the controller

Comment: your controller called two times. how you bind controller to the page. using ng-controller or routing? or both

Comment: Not to mention that this is mainly jQuery code, **not** AngularJS code...

Comment: did you call the controller from html side and routing side???

Comment: Actually I want to Click on one page and want to fire on another page thats why I wrote two controllers

Comment: I called controller from html page using ng-controller

Comment: Please  use find control on your html page for this `ng-controller`

Comment: Yo've done unnecesary work here. Send your model in the function click and forgot the rest. Be more angular guy

Comment: I want to call some API on button click and want to display API's content on another view that is table. It works properly but only issue is it fires 2 times..

Answer (score 0):

I hope your getting the data from HTML page to controller

In controller:

```
$scope.onSearchButton1Click = function() {
        var partId = $("#partIdSearch").val();
        var firstName = $("#firstNameSearch").val();
        var lastName = $("#lastNameSearch").val();
        var fathersName = $("#fathersNameSearch").val();
        var address = $("#address").val();

     //calling the service 
     var url ="api/search" + "?part_id="+data1 +"&first_name="+data2+"&middle_name="+data3+"&last_name="+data4+"&subpart=" + data5 +"&page_no="+pageNo;

     // alert("url"+url);

        $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: url ,
                    headers: { 
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                    },
                }).
                success(function (data) {
                    if(data != null && data.length > 0){
                       $log.info("It is in success of onSearchButton1Click()  -------");                  
                       $scope.searchResult = angular.fromJson(data);
                      $log.info("searchResult Details==============> "+JSON.stringify($scope.searchResult ));
                     }else{
                          $log.info("searchResult=> in else:"+$scope.searchResult .length);

                      }

                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                     $log.info("searchResultUrl=> FAILURE:");

                });



}
```

In this way your able to call the service when ever user click on search button only and no external unnecessary calls to web service.

Comment: i want to know about further information , now activate the alert below the url and count how many times it alerts and clear the console in browser and count the $log.info statements. I need these answers for change the code

Comment: Actually my rootScope broadcast event  fires only once but it catches twice.How to resolve this please help..

Comment: yah,this is the problem of mapping RouteManager action part with some were else in html like id ,click names or in controller $location.path() mapping extra time or another time ,so be specific with RouteManager action part not not to use these names unnecessary in html and controller.

Comment: I couldn't use $location.path() mapping anywhere in code

Comment: can u create the exact problem of jsFiddle or plunker or jsbin.

Answer (score 0):

We have to initialize our controller only once in a app, in above problem I was initialize my controller two times (i.e. in a html and app.js file), that's why it initialize's two times and all functions are called two time that is totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, then realized I had 2 tabs open in Chrome running my app at the same time.  I closed one of them and now it is perfectly fine.  I feel stupid.